# Disemvowel Trolls - Javascript

Tags: javascript

1st week into a JS and trying to solve first Kata in CodeWars.

Your task is to write a function that takes a string and return a new string with all vowels removed.
For example, the string "This website is for losers LOL!" would become "Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!".

My code:

```js
function disemvowel(str) {
  var newStr = "";
  for (i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != "a" || str.charAt(i) != "e" || str.charAt(i) != "i" || str.charAt(i) != "o" || str.charAt(i) != "u") {
      newStr += str.charAt(i)
    }
    return newStr;
  }
}
```

Expected: 'Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!', instead got: 'T'

Why does my loop stops? It doesn't continue with i++? Probably beginner's mistake. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Move the `return` outside of the loop.

Comment: Also, `i <= str.length` would lead to an off-by-one error.

Comment: Also, your `||` should be `&&`.

Comment: Also, it can be more easily solved with a regular expression: `return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');`

Comment: `function disemvowel(str){ return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, ''); }`

Comment: what is the learning target of this kata?

Comment: `const disemvowel = str => str.replace(/[aeiouy]/gi, '');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some annotations:

- declare `i`,
- loop until `i < str.length`, because arrays and strings are zero based,
- take a string for checking a character with [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes),
- use a single character by taking a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with the index, instead of [`String.charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) (it is shorter),
- take a small letter case for checking
- [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) the `for` statement, if a character is found,
- move the [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) to the end of the function.

```js
function disemvowel(str) {
    var newStr = "",
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if ("aeiou".includes(str[i].toLowerCase())) continue;
        newStr += str[i];
    }
    return newStr;
}

console.log(disemvowel("This website is for losers LOL!"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let str = ('This website is for losers LOL!'.replace(/A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u/g, ''))

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution !

```
function disemvowel(str) {
 let newStr = (str.replace(/A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u/g, ''))
 return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function disemvowel(str) {
   return str.match(/[^aeiou]/gi).join('');  
 }
```

Comment: Explain your snippet...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.